# How to hide the job submission message of SLURM's sbatch

Tags: python, cluster-computing, slurm, sbatch

I am trying to hide "Submitted batch job xxxx" message after running `sbatch -Q -N 16 -c 8 --time 10:00:00 job.sh`.

However, the message "Submitted batch job xxxx" still comes out. Is anyone familiar with the situation?

According to SLURM documentation,

```
-Q, --quiet
    Suppress informational messages from sbatch such as Job ID. 
    Only errors will still be displayed.
```

Comment: You can always redirect the output of any command to `null`.

Comment: @Poshi Thank you. But if I do that in command line, I will redirect every output to ```null```. I would like to only hide "Submitted ..." information.

Comment: Hummm... and which other output are you expecting??? Anyways, after the `--quiet` option you should not expect anything.

Comment: @Poshi so for example, I have own print messages in my script file, and let's say my print message is a process bar which update itself on output. In this case, I'll hate to see messages of ```sbatch``` to come out. My script has added ```--quiet``` or ```-Q``` flag, but messages keep coming out. Is there anything else I should add to incorporate ```-Q```?

Comment: But you are running `sbatch`, not your script. Your print messages from your script should not appear (just because it is not being run at this point).